# Count calculated Column in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have SSRS report where in I am using table with 7 columns (Date, Job ID, Job Name, Status, Output Count, Expected Count, Flag). Out of 7 columns , 4 are directly coming from dataset. Rest three (Job Name, Expected Count, Flag) are calculated columns. I am getting their values from either SSRS custom code or expression. I want to count those rows where Output Count and Expected Count are not matching. Also I have Flag column where I am using Background Color property to check if values are matching or not. So even if I can get count of rows having Red background at Flag column will also server my purpose. Please help me in achieving the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can create some new fields for your dataset to handle calculated values. Then, in your report, you can add some groups and add count or sum values on the table.